# Multiply a table(file1) with individual cells of a column(file2) using R

Tags: r

File 1:
Ele A B C D
Es 1 2 3 4
Ep 2 4 3 4
Ek 1 9 3 8
File2:
A 1 
 B 2
 C 3
 D 5

Need is to ensure that each element under Column A (file 1) gets multiplied by the value assigned to A in file 2 (and so on). I know matrix multiplication in R but this is not the case of matrix multiplication I suppose. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
indx <- df2$Col1
df1[indx]*df2$Col2[col(df1[indx])]
#  A  B C  D
#1 1  4 9 20
#2 2  8 9 20
#3 1 18 9 40
```

Or you could use `sweep`

```
sweep(df1[indx],  2, df2$Col2, '*')
#  A  B C  D
#1 1  4 9 20
#2 2  8 9 20
#3 1 18 9 40
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Ele = c("Es", "Ep", "Ek"), A = c(1L, 2L, 1L), 
B = c(2L, 4L, 9L), C = c(3L, 3L, 3L), D = c(4L, 4L, 8L)), 
.Names = c("Ele", "A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Col2 = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! but those were just sample files; actual files are huge in size (5670x2781: file1) and (2781x1: file2). I'm quite naive in R; but your solution seems specific to the small data files I provided. I am able to do the processing in perl; but it takes 1-2 minutes to completion; I am aiming at doing it through R to make it faster (perl, shell and R is all I know).

Comment: @NaSu The first solution would be fast enough.  Regarding the solution, I did check by trying it on a unordered df2 dataset.  It seems to work.  I don't know why you said it is specific.  May be provide a small example that mimics your dataset would be more useful.

Comment: if my first file is named file1.txt (containing a matrix of 5670x2781) numbers and other as file2.txt (containing a matrix of 2781x1) numbers; how would I go about it after reading the files using read.table. Use of  "structure(list(Ele = c("Es", "Ep", "Ek"), A = c(1L, 2L, 1L), 
B = c(2L, 4L, 9L), C = c(3L, 3L, 3L), D = c(4L, 4L, 8L))" gives me a feeling that the code is relying on some specific headers; which in my case can be dynamic.

Comment: @NaSu You don't need the `structure...` stuff.  You can read it by `read.table/read.csv`  or `fread` from `data.table`.  The structure output was created with `dput` to give a reproducible code so that copy/pasting the code gives you the output I got instead of thinking what might be the column class etc.